Loadcell Reading loss after long time
I am using an stm32f100 series microcontroller and TAL221 loadcell (100g) with Hx711 ADC
The problem is that the loadcell count decreases after about 30 minutes or 1hr
Please help me to solve this.
I am using
https://github.com/nimaltd/HX711 library for Hx711.

when you remove the load after it's indicated load has dropped  does the indicated load go back to 0?

Please provide more details. Is the load cell count decreasing since the load is evaporating during the 30 minutes or 1hr.

For answer to Greg locok     No it will indicate the diffrence that loadcell drift over time    for example if I apply 10mg then after over the time it will indicate 0g even if 10mg is their but then after take back load it will indicate -10mg kind of result

Then you have creep in your strain gages or a very odd instrumentation/analysis setup.

You should do an on online search for "Creep in Load Cells"  This seems to be a common problem.
I found this after just a minutes search:
Creep in load cells: from 800loadcell.com
"Creep in load cells is a phenomenon where the output gradually changes when a constant load is applied over time. This occurs due to the viscoelastic properties of the materials used in the load cell, which deform slowly under continuous stress. Creep is particularly problematic in applications that demand high precision and long-term stability, as it can lead to substantial measurement errors.
The materials in load cells, such as metals and strain gauges, are prone to time-dependent deformation under sustained loads. This deformation results in a slow shift in the load cell output, even though the load itself remains unchanged. Factors such as temperature, humidity, and the load's magnitude can influence the rate of creep. Employing load cells crafted with materials that exhibit low creep and maintaining controlled environmental conditions can significantly mitigate this issue.
To effectively minimize creep in load cells, consider the following strategies:
Opt for load cells manufactured with materials known for their low creep characteristics.
Allow a sufficient warm-up period before conducting measurements to stabilize the load cell.
Regularly calibrate the load cell to adjust for any creep-induced deviations.
Implement environmental controls to ensure that conditions such as temperature and humidity remain stable.

Adopting these measures can greatly reduce the impact of creep on load cell accuracy and reliability."

Thank For Your Responce I will try this
